# How to capture video from ip camera iOs iPad/iPhone

Tags: ios, camera, ip, capture

How to capture video from ip camera iOs iPad/iPhone

Comment: Is it a programming question at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want to implement it:**

Well, You can use RTSP Protocol to get streams from IP Camera...[Most of the IP Cameras support RTSP..]  Also you need an decoder to show streams on your platform...This depends on streams codec from IP Camera...

**If you just want to get see IP Camera streams**

You can use VLC  player for iOS [ http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html]...Just learn the rtsp url format from the IP Cameara manufacturer and connect it via VLC Player.

VLC Player has RTSP protocol support and it has many decoders...